# AspNetCore not getting POST data initially in framework 4.6.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I've just updated my Azure Web App from aspnetcore rc2 to aspnetcore 1.0, .net framework 4.6.2 and preview 2 tooling. Since this change I've had an issue where for the first minute or so after deploy my controller is not getting any POST data. The object that should contain it is always null. After a minute or so the code begins to work as expected.
Response time to the first web call seems much faster now, making me suspect that my app is being sent requests before the app is fully initialised. This does not happen locally, only when deployed to Azure.

Is there anything I need to do to ensure that the app is fully initialised before it starts to receive requests?

If I try to access this.HttpContext.Request.Body directly then it throws

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.
```

My project.json looks like this in case it's relevant:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

    "frameworks": {
      "net462": {
      }
    },
    "publishOptions": {
      "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
      ]
    },

    "userSecretsId": "redacted",

    "scripts": {
      "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    }
  }
```

The code for the controller is pretty simple. In the first minute or so this will return badrequest, after that the same request will return Ok.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces( "application/json" )]
    public IActionResult Post( [FromBody] MyRequestDataClass RequestData )
    {
        if (RequestData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Post your code maybe?

Comment: It feels more like a config issue than a code issue, but I've added a snippet from my controller

Comment: Create new aspnet core web api project and check project.json, I think you should rename some properties

Comment: [Binding Include=""] ?